# Quickest way to merge dictionaries based on key match

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dictionaries:

```
dic_1={'1234567890': 1, '1234567891': 2, '1234567880': 3, '1234567881': 4}
dic_2={'1234567890': 5, '1234567891': 6}
```

Now I want to merge them based on key values such that the merged dictionary looks like the following:

```
merged_dic=={'1234567890': 1, '1234567891': 2, '1234567880': 3, '1234567881': 4}
```

We only want to keep unique keys and only one distinct value associated with them. What's the best way to do that

Comment: Is there a specific performance issue with your current implementation?

Comment: i dont understand the question, whats the difference between dic_1 and merged_dic ?

Comment: What actually gets merged here? your output is the same as `dic_1`

Comment: so the merged dictionary checks if there is already a value assigned for a key, for example in Dic_2 "123456789" has value 5, but in dic_1 the value for same number is 1, so when we merge the dictionary the merged dictionary will go with whatever value was assigned in dictionary one ofr the number 123456789,

Comment: So you want to use `update()` but keep the old keys and values instead of have it overwrite them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: You're essentially just trying to update `dic_2` with values from `dic_1`

Comment: so dic_1 and dic_2 will have some common keys and some distinct keys, the merged dictionary should look for common keys and if any value has already been assigned with it, it will go with it, and if the key is not common then it will keep adding, to sum up the merged dictionary should only have distinct keys with a value assigned with it

Comment: You should show what you've tried. Its possible to do this in 17 characters.

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you need. It iterates through all dictionaries adding key/values only if the key is not already in the merged dictionary.

```py
from itertools import chain

merged_dic = {}

for k, v in chain(dic_1.items(), dic_2.items()):
    if k not in merged_dic:
        merged_dic[k] = v

print(merged_dic)
# {'1234567890': 1, '1234567891': 2, '1234567880': 3, '1234567881': 4}
```

If, for example, you were wanting to keep all values for a key you could use:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

merged_dic = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in chain(dic_1.items(), dic_2.items()):
    merged_dic[k].append(v)

print(merged_dic)
# {'1234567890': [1, 5], '1234567891': [2, 6], '1234567880': [3], '1234567881': [4]}
```

Using `chain()` can allow you to iterate over many dictionaries. In the question you showed 2 dictionaries, but if you had 4 you could easily merge them all. E.g.

```
for k, v in chain(dic_1.items(), dic_2.items(), dic_3.items(), dic_4.items()):
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample data is not exactly explains the SO.  If dic_2 has common key with dic_1 then retain the item in dic_1; if new item is found in dic_2 then put it in merged dictionary.

```
import copy
dic_1={'1234567890': 1, '1234567891': 2, '1234567880': 3, '1234567881': 4}
dic_2={'1234567890': 5, '8234567890': 6}

merged_d = copy.copy(dic_1)
diff = set(dic_2)-set(dic_1)
merged_d.update({k: dic_2[k] for k in diff})
print(merged_d)
```

Result:

```
{'1234567890': 1, '1234567891': 2, '1234567880': 3, '1234567881': 4, '8234567890': 6}
```

Comment: You would want to copy `dic_1` rather than use `merged_d = dic_1` as any updates to `dic_1` will also update `merged_d` (i.e. they point to the same object) :)

Answer (score 0):

All you're really trying to do is update `dic_2` with any values in `dic_1` so you can just do

```
merged_dic = {**dic_2,**dic_1}
```

This will merge the two dictionaries, taking all the values from `dic_2`, updating any keys in the new dictionary with any new values that exist in `dic_1` and then adding any unique keys in `dic_1`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first dict to override the keys in the second dict then:

```
dic_2.update(dic_1)
```